How would one access an Inner class from outside of all classes?
I have a class (MainApplication) that envelopes all my other classes, and an if statement that is outside of the outer class. I'm struggling to figure out how to access 'Start' from that if statement, so the program will start.
import tkinter as tk

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        class charName (object):
            def __init__ (self, master):
                Top = self.Top = tk.Toplevel(master)
                self.l= tk.Label(Top, text="Test")
                self.l.pack()
                self.e = tk.Entry(Top)
                self.e.pack()
                self.b = tk.Button(Top, text="Next", command=self.Cleanup,)
                self.b.pack()
                Top.mainloop
            
            def Cleanup (self):
                self.value = self.e.get()
                self.command = print("Works!")
                self.Top.destroy




        class Start (object):
            def __init__(self, master):
                self.master=master
                self.b = tk.Button(root, 
                            text="Get Started!", 
                            command=self.popup,)
                
                self.b.pack()
                
                    
            def popup (self):
                self.w = charName(self.master)
                self.b["state"] = "disabled" 
                self.master(self.w.Top)
                self.b["state"] = "normal"
                
                
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    m=Start(root)
    root.mainloop()

I've tried getting rid of the MainApplication, and it works great.  Other than that, I'm not sure what else I can do. I read from another post that the MainApplication code would work for organizing objects (I'm not quite sure what I'm doing) but I was trying to make this part of the code open a screen that would allow you to input a character name, then (in different code) choose race, class, and other necessities for creating a DnD character, with code to organize where the buttons are.
Also, sorry that this post is so long. I'm new to python (and this) and am not quite sure that I know what I'm doing, what's needed or what's not. Thanks for your patience.
import tkinter as tk


class charName (object):
    def __init__ (self, master):
        Top = self.Top = tk.Toplevel(master)
        self.l= tk.Label(Top, text="Test")
        self.l.pack()
        self.e = tk.Entry(Top)
        self.e.pack()
        self.b = tk.Button(Top, text="Next", command=self.Cleanup,)
        self.b.pack()
        Top.mainloop
    
    def Cleanup (self):
        self.value = self.e.get()
        self.command = print("Works!")
        self.Top.destroy




class Start (object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.b = tk.Button(root, 
                    text="Get Started!", 
                    command=self.popup,)
        
        self.b.pack()
        
            
    def popup (self):
        self.w = charName(self.master)
        self.b["state"] = "disabled" 
        self.master(self.w.Top)
        self.b["state"] = "normal"
                
                
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    m=Start(root)
    root.mainloop()


Why do you hide the classes in there?

I'll be honest, I'm not quite sure what I'm doing, I think I was hiding the classes in there so that the MainApplication could be used later for window organizing.

You don't need this Top.mainloop. You already have root.aminloop().

Without the parentheses, it's not doing anything anyway. Same with self.Top.destroy.

Python lets you define classes and functions inside other classes, functions, and methods. But 90% of the time, you shouldn't. Unless you know what you're doing and know you have a good reason to avoid doing so, define all your classes (and free functions, if any) at the top level of your code.

Thank you for your advice, I'll change my code a bit :D

Does this help?
def popup (self):
    self.w = charName(self.master)
    if True:
        self.b["state"] = "disabled" 
    #self.master(self.w.Top)
    else:    
        self.b["state"] = "normal"


If you want to call the constructor of the inner class, you have to first instantiate the outer class:
class Outer():
    def __init__(self):
        # Do some things
    class Inner():
        def __init__(self, num):
            print(num)
            
outer = Outer()
outer.Inner(1) # prints 1


It is not necessary to create instance of Outer for your case, Outer.Inner(1) will work as well.  Note that OP code defines those classes inside __init__() and they are not actually inner class.  They are just classes defined locally inside __init__() and cannot be accessed outside the function.

Good point, I didn't catch that the inner classes were inside the __innit__()
